# Checking for null string in bash

Tags: linux, bash

Is there any difference between the following tests?

```
[[ "$STRING" = "" ]] && exit 1;


[[ "x$STRING" = "x" ]] && exit 1;


[[ -z $STRING ]] && exit 1;
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Nope, they are all the same. But couple of defensive habits to get into.

- You should quote the `$STRING` in the `-z` one as well
- If you are running with the -u option (I always do) then you should reference the possibly optional variable as `${STRING-}` just in case its not set at all

Comment: Why would you quote `$STRING` when using the `[[`  keyword?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, they all do the same thing, that is check if the given string its "empty", except that the first one checks if $string its empty, the second checks whether x plus $string its equals to x and finally, -z that checks the length.
Personally I'd ratter go with -z that's more realiable.

Comment: You don't need to quote $string in the -z one, and on the first example too, specially if you know that $string will contain a string.

Comment: Quoting strings is a good habit and makes a real difference if you do more complex tests like: `[[ -z "$STRING" && -z "$OTHER" ]]`.