# What does -z mean in Bash?

Tags: bash

I'm looking at the following code:

```
if [ -z $2 ]; then
        echo "usage: ...
```

(The 3 dots are irrelevant usage details.)
Maybe I'm googling it wrong, but I couldn't find an explanation for the `-z` option.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6665541/checking-for-null-string-in-bash

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228544/how-to-tell-if-a-string-is-not-defined-in-a-bash-shell-script

Answer (score 716, accepted):

`-z string`: True if the string is null (an empty string)

See https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-Conditional-Expressions

Comment: I found another one excellent and detailed explanation - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3601515/how-to-check-if-a-variable-is-set-in-bash

Comment: Also, `-n` is the opposite of `-z`. `if [ -n "${1}" ]` passes if the string is not null and not empty.

Comment: Is `-n` redundant with the default behavior of `if [ $2 ]` or are there some differences?

Answer (score 75):

```
-z

string is null, that is, has zero length

String=''   # Zero-length ("null") string variable.

if [ -z "$String" ]
then
  echo "\$String is null."
else
  echo "\$String is NOT null."
fi     # $String is null.
```

Answer (score 39):

`test -z` returns true if the parameter is empty (see [`man sh`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sh) or [`man test`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/test)).

Answer (score 36):

The expression `-z string` is true if the length of string is `zero`.

Comment: What if it is the string undefined (if that is a thing) or is a number?

Comment: @PeterMortensen if you use `if [[ -z "${YOUR_ENV_VAR}" ]]` it will get interpolated to `if [[ -z "" ]]` at runtime when that env var is empty, thus resulting in a logical true, which is what you want.