# Difference between `if [ ! -z "$var" ] then` and `if [ "$var"] then" in bash

Tags: bash

Is there any difference between

```
if [ ! -z "$var" ] then
    # do smth
fi
```

and

```
if [ "$var" ] then
    # do smth
fi
```

They both seem to check if variable is set

Comment: -z string True if the string is null (an empty string) -- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18096670/what-does-z-mean-in-bash

Comment: @BookOfZeus That means that `! -z` is true if the string is *not* empty. Which is what `[ "$var" ]` also tests.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, they're equivalent, but there are a couple of notes that apply to both of them:

- You need either a semicolon or a line break between `]` and the `then` keyword, or it'll misparse them weirdly.
- They're not testing whether the variable is set, they're testing whether it's set *to something other than the empty string* (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3601515/how-to-check-if-a-variable-is-set-in-bash) for ways to check whether a variable is truly unset).

However, I actually prefer a third also-equivalent option:

```
if [ -n "$var" ]; then
```

I consider this semantically clearer, because the `-n` operator specifically checks for something being **n**on-empty.

Comment: Ah, thanks for detailed answer!

Answer (score 1):

There's no difference between

```
[ ! -z "$var" ]
[ -n "$var" ]
[ "$var" ]
```

All of them are true if `$var` is not empty.