# Is there an advantage to using the -z test in bash?

Tags: bash

From `man test`:

```
       ! EXPRESSION
              EXPRESSION is false
```

and

```
       -n STRING
              the length of STRING is nonzero

       STRING equivalent to -n STRING

       -z STRING
              the length of STRING is zero
```

So `[ "$x" ]` has the same effect as `[ -n "$x" ]` (that's explicitly stated above) and implicitly, `[ ! "$x" ]` has the same effect as `[ -z "$x" ]`.  So why would one choose to use `-n` or `-z` when arguably the other forms are clearer?  Is it just personal preference or am I missing an important distinction?

I've seen other questions (e.g. [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18096670/1999993)) about this but nothing to say for definite if they're functionally identical.  I did wonder whether I could avoid quoting `$x` if I used `-n` or `-z` but if `$x` contains a space, this fails as with the other methods.

Answer (score 9):

> Is there an advantage to using the -z test in bash?

No.

> why would one choose to use -n or -z when **arguably** the other forms are clearer?

Because it is arguable which form is "clearer"...

Of course `-n` and `-z` are better, because `-z` is like "Zero" and `-n` is like "Nonzero" or "Nonempty", it's easier for me to read it. `[ -n "$x" ]` is "if `$x` is Nonzero". I recommend* `-n` and `-z`.

> Is it just personal preference

Yes.

> am I missing an important distinction?

No.

In Bash prefer `[[`, if you do not need POSIX compatibility.

> I did wonder whether I could avoid quoting $x if I used -n or -z

No. You can avoid quoting if you use `[[`. I recommend* quoting every expansion anyway to get used to quoting always, to reduce accidental mistakes.

* - this is only a suggestion, not a limit. If you sent me code with `[ ! "$x" ]` or `[[ $x ]]` I will not blink twice. But if you sent `[ $x ]` smoke will come out of my ears.

Comment: [... or worse](https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original/qCCo807zQcj4kaSGn5H6LTqK2dh.jpg)

Comment: Thanks for the discussion @KamilCuk.  I deliberately put the word "arguably" in there because I forget what the tests are (e.g. sometimes I think `-z` is a test for zero file size) and so getting rid of flags is getting rid of something that I have to remember.  Totally agree about your final `[ $x ]` comment! :-D